# Kubuntu 18.10 Nvidia GTX 1050 OpenCL compatibility

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, opencl

I recently bought a laptop with a gtx1050 in it installed Kubuntu after a lot of struggling I and a friend managed to install the nvidia-driver-415 and cuda 10. However I want to use this card with hashcat which require OpenCL and here where te problem start. All these packets are installed on my system:

```
libnvidia-cfg1-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-415/cosmic,cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-opencl-dev/cosmic,now 9.1.85-4ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-prime/cosmic,cosmic,now 0.8.10 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-415/cosmic,now 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

uname -a:

```
Linux Samuel-PcPortable 4.18.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 5 09:04:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However hachcat -b spit this error out:

```
hashcat (v4.2.1) starting in benchmark mode...

Benchmarking uses hand-optimized kernel code by default. You can use it in your cracking session by setting the -O option. Note: Using optimized kernel code limits the maximum supported password length. To disable the optimized kernel code in benchmark mode, use the -w option.

* Device #1: Intel's OpenCL runtime (GPU only) is currently broken.
             We are waiting for updated OpenCL drivers from Intel.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
* Device #2: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors. No devices found/left.

Started: Fri Jan 25 22:36:27 2019 Stopped: Fri Jan 25 22:36:28 2019
```

Device 1 and 2 are respectively my CPU and CPU-Intergated graphics
I've tried these combinaisons of kernel/nvidia-driver: 4.18/415 4.18/410 4.18/396 4.15/415 4.15/410

nvidia-cuda-toolkit is also installed

What would be the steps to install opencl on the driver 415 on the kernel 4.18 ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/785762/186740 this was the simplest way around the whole issue without adding ppa sources

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem by following this tutorial: [https://hashcat.net/faq/wrongdriver](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#i_may_have_the_wrong_driver_installed_what_should_i_do)  But not using apt install to install the nvidia drive but downloading them for the site. You also need to kill Xorg before installing the driver